# Provide functionality from newer system

Tags: user-expectation, hyperlinks

I have a question about cross-linking or embedding or if there is a more suitable option.

#### The Requirement

So we're developing a web app with new functionality, but our older system is still widely used. Now our boss decided that it would be a good idea if the old system could also benefit from the new funtionality, but without the need of implementing it twice. This also includes the UI, which is a bit of a problem for me because the systems look and feel entirely differently.

#### My approaches

I'm trying to find a way to make certain pages of the new web app usable in the old web app, with as little irritation to the user as possible. So far, I only came up with the "classical" approaches of **a)** embedding the site or **b)** placing a link which opens the site in a new tab.

#### My questions

Is there another, probably better approach? Is it recommended to inform the users about what is going to happen when clicking on a link that leads them somewhere else? What works best with user expectation, as I don't want to throw them off.

(If it is relevant: people use our systems in a professional context and they have to work with our software. The thing I'm worried about is that users might be irritated and lose focus on their task.)

Comment: "...it would be a good idea if the old system could also benefit from the new funtionality, but without the need of implementing it twice."An interesting, and likely common scenario. — The question comes to mind, what in the new system is necessarily so different that it is apparently an obstacle for users to make the switch?

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this situation is to put a banner on top of the page (that can be closed of course) where I inform them that a new and improved version of the web app is available. Something in the lines of: "Try myAPP 2.0 with this new benefit and that new benefit ".

Meanwhile, until users will upgrade to the new version, I would implement version B instead of mixing the two versions of the system with embeds. But please: Test, test, test!